# How to connect to postgres server running on ec2 instance

Tags: postgresql

I followed [this guide](https://installvirtual.com/install-postgresql-11-on-amazon-linux-compile/) to install postgres on an AL2 server and I have it running. On the server, I can run `psql -d mydatabase` and it works fine. But when I log off the instance and try to reach it from my local machine with `psql postgres://ec2-user@<ip.address.here>:5432/mydatabase` I get:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "ip.address.here" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The issue is not with security groups as I can access the machine that fine, and I've opened up all ports. How can I connect to it remotely?

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify postgresql.conf `listen_addresses` to include the ip addresses, then restart the server.

`listen_addresses = 'localhost,0.0.0.0,<ip.address.here>'`